# How to find error on a single measurement?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, descriptive-statistics

This is really a basic question. I have three data points zipcode = [02145, 02143, 02144] and price = [90, 1050, 9880]. Let's say I need to regress zip code vs house price. I know that the house price is normally distributed and the mean values are [100, 1000, 10000]. However, these mean values are unknown to me. I could not determine the mean and std. dev. of the price without more measurements at a particular zipcode. Can we do anything with that single observed point at a zipcode using statistics? If yes, can I find random and/or systematic errors using only one observation in a zipcode? Should I need to regress these three points to find the error? Is that a model dependent error?

Comment: Are you doing linear regression on the zipcode? Zipcode is the classic categorical variable that looks like a quantitative. Or are you doing logistic regression?

Comment: Not doing any analysis but I'm trying to figure out this question. The data can be an observed y as a function of x. However, only one value of y can be observed at a specific point in x, i.e. at x=10, y=5. Is there any statistical answer to this?

Comment: Statistics, by its very nature, is concerned with reasoning from a sample (always, the bigger the better) to the population. The smaller the sample, less that you can say about it. If you have a sample size of 1 from three groups, you can say almost nothing about it.

Comment: Please add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us what you understand thus far, what 
you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll provide hints to 
help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just 
posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you 
is grounds for closing.